# Variable case list in switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have a somewhat complicated need for a switch statement with a variable case list. It would look like this in pseudo-code..

```
switch(check){
case 1:
case 2:
..
case etc: do something
break; 
}
```

in theory the case list would be generated off an array where I don't know the amount of possible case values beforehand.

```
[1,2,3,4,5 ... ]
```

is this possible?

Comment: You seem to be looking for help by telling us your solution but if we know the problem we might come to the conclusion that there are much better and simpler ways to achieve what you want, could you please share your issue too?

Comment: If you don't know the amount of possible case values, then how do you know what you want to do with those unknown case values? Are you intending that `case 1` will fall through the the following cases?

Comment: I second Sidney's comment - I get the sense that a switch statement isn't the right tool for the job. It would be useful to see the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @gargantaun that is exactly my point my friend, re-read ;)

Comment: Each case would define a specific value of one variable. If you don't know the possible values of your var beforehand, then switch would not be very useful.

Comment: I'm intending that a statement execute if it's case is found in the array. I thought there may have been a way to overload the switch statement but it seems I'll have to use multiple if statements as @Alexander suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think impossible programmatically generate `cases` for `switch`. Maybe in this case better use `if-else` with `indexOf`, like this

```js
var data = [1,2,3,4,5];
var check = 1;

if (data.indexOf(check) >= 0) {
  // to do something
}
```